# Openstack Python code **kwargs -> help=_('Password for connection to nova in admin context')

Tags: python, openstack

I want to analyze OpenStack code for research.
but I am not familiar with Python.
I don't understand why that code have single under score -> help=_('string')
I can't find that shape in python book
plz help me to know usage of that grammer in python Thanks
This is oslo_config package with cfg module...

class oslo_config.cfg.BoolOpt(name, **kwargs)

Parameters: 
name – the option’s name
**kwargs – arbitrary keyword arguments passed to Opt

```
from oslo_config import cfg
core_opts = [
    cfg.BoolOpt('allow_bulk', default=True,
                help=_("Allow the usage of the bulk API")),
    cfg.BoolOpt('allow_pagination', default=False,
                help=_("Allow the usage of the pagination")),
    cfg.StrOpt('api_paste_config', default="api-paste.ini",
               help=_("The API paste config file to use")),
    cfg.StrOpt('api_extensions_path', default="",
               help=_("The path for API extensions")),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `_()` is there to support text translation. It is an alias for the [`gettext()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/gettext.html#gettext.gettext) function in the [`gettext`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/gettext.html#module-gettext) module.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! :) I have one more question! Do you know some document or site related to OpenStack Code? or plz Recommand me some important things when I analyze big code like OpenStack! Thanks!

Comment: @MINSIKKIM: no problem. The way to say thanks on SO is by up voting and accepting answers. I don't know about OpenStack but I'm sure that google could help you find the info you need.